SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) Azure Feature Pack - Need installed on Sql Server?
My question is: is there a need for installing the  Azure Feature Pack for Integration Services (SSIS) on the sql server as well?
I have installed Azure Feature Pack for Integration Services (SSIS) on my pc
to use it in Visual Studio.
I have made a package with a Flexible File Task to handle upload to Azure blob container.
It works fine, my issue arise when I deploy it to the onpremise sql server SSIS.
My Flexible File Task is named : "Upload data file to Azure"
And I get this error:
Upload data file to Azure:Error: Failed to load task "Upload data file to Azure", type "". The contact information for this task is "".


SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) Feature Pack for Azure is an extension that provides the components listed on this page for SSIS to connect to Azure services, transfer data between Azure and on-premises data sources, and process data stored in Azure.

You should install the SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) Feature Pack for Azure on your SQL Server.

The Feature Pack includes components for connecting to services like  Azure Blob Storage,  Azure HDInsight,  Azure Data Lake Store, and  Azure Synapse Analytics.

Make sure you install SQL Server before adding the Azure Feature Pack to ensure availability of these components when deploying packages to the SSIS Catalog database (SSISDB) on the server.


For more information you can refer below MS documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/azure-feature-pack-for-integration-services-ssis?view=sql-server-ver16

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/install-integration-services?view=sql-server-ver16


